# How to make a simple DFAFC (direct formic acid fuel cell)?

Tags: electricity

So, I want to take some Formic Acid and make a DFAFC using it. I don't want something really complex, just something simple, and can turn on a light bulb. What metals will I need for the electrodes, and can I do it in a beaker? Do I need to use expensive catalysts like palladium or platinum, or is that not necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't *'turn it [formic acid] into electricity'* do that.

In a trypical homemade cell deploying acid [like a lemon battery](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GhbuhT1GDpI&ab_channel=SciShow), the acid is only the so-called *[electrolyte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrolyte)*, which carries the charge  from cathode to anode. Formic acid will definitely also work but it's a slightly 'exotic' choice.

There are other combinations of metals that can be used for an acid battery than the ones shown in the video, so Google is your friend.

And other electrolytes like salt brine or potato (instead of lemon) will also work.

Comment: (+1) Excellent answer that emphasizes that the electrolyte is just the electrolyte. For a thorough discussion of where the free energy comes from in a related cell (the Daniell cell), see this paper: K. Schmidt-Rohr, "How Batteries Store and Release Energy: Explaining Basic Electrochemistry", J. Chem. Ed., 95 (10) (2018) 1801-1810. The Zn and Cu Daniell cell is addressed in great detail. TL; DR Cohesive energy differences are the major factor in explaining the behavior of this famous galvanic cell. In a lemon cell, the oxidation of the anode metal is the main contributor.

Comment: @EdV Thanks Ed, much obliged.

Comment: Hi, I saw your answer, and I appreciate it. I do know I can use lemon, salt brine, or potato, but the thing is the goal is to use formic acid. Do you perhaps have any suggestions on the metal that I should use for this experiment? Also, do I need to use a catalyst for the experiment?

Comment: Any combination of an *electropositive* metal and an *electronegative* one will work. For the former, think $\text{Al}$, $\text{Mg}$, $\text{Zn}$, $\text{Sn}$, $\text{Pb}$. For the latter think $\text{Cu}$, $\text{Ag}$, $\text{Pt}$, $\text{Au}$. No catalyst is needed.

Comment: @Gert Thanks a lot

Comment: @Gert I have done some research, and I have been wondering, due to the high conc. of the formic acid I'm using, can I use copper for a cathode and silver for an anode, since they are noble metals?

Comment: Strong formic acid will probably attack copper *mildly* but that shouldn't worry you too much.